# Trying to have an array with 2 values in side by side

Tags: php

I need to create an array where i can use 1,2,3 but have 1v1, 2v2, Clubs associated with them.

I am going to use 1,2,3 for option value and 1v1,2v2 and clubs to display to the user.

How can I store this in an array and then use foreach to extract?
Thanks

Comment: are you after a multidimensional array?

Comment: Perhaps you could elaborate on your question? The three answers so far are confused as to what you're trying to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = array(
    1 => '1v1',
    2 => '2v2',
    3 => 'Clubs';
);

echo '<select>';
foreach($data as $value => $title) {
    echo '<option value="'.$value.'">'.$title.'</option>';
}
echo '</select>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make your original values (1,2,3) the keys and the (1v1, 2v2, Clubs) the values.

```
$data = array(1 => '1v1', 2 => '2v2', 3 => 'Clubs');

foreach($data as $key => $value) {
   print $key.' - '.$value.'<br/>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, I don't understand your question. try to use the next array:

```
$array = array(1 => '1v1', 2 => '2v2');
```

And foreach:

```
<select>
<? foreach ($array as $k => $v) { ?>
   <option value="<?= $k ?>"><?= $v ?></option>
<? } ?>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the question, but it seems like you want to map the values 1,2,3 to the text '1v1','2v2','Clubs'. PHP supports associative arrays that are suitable for this purpose:

```
$a = Array(
   1 => '1v1',
   2 => '2v2',
   3 => 'Clubs'
);
```